# Extract columns from a csv file with fields containing delimited values

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, talend

I am trying to extract certain fields from a csv file, having comma separated values.
The issues is , some of the fields also contains comma and the fields are not enclosed within quotes. Given the scenario, how can i extract the fields.

also,only one of the field contains comma within values, and i don't need that. e.g: I want to extract the first 2 columns and the last 5 columns from the data set of 8 columns , where the third column contains values with comma

> PS: Instead of down voting i would suggest to come ahead and post your
>   brilliant ideas if you have any.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: CSV files split on commas, if you want commas inside lines you need to have them escaped, otherwise there's no way for the computer to know which should be split on. fix your file.

Comment: There is a way that i did on linux.
`step 1:  cut the first 2 columns
step 2: reverse the file
step 3: cut the first 5 columns after reverse and merge with step 1.`

but how can i do this using powershell or talend

Comment: this is what i tried and its working in bash
`for filename in *.csv; do
    paste  -d, <(cut -d, -f -2 "$filename") <(rev "$filename" | cut -d, -f -7 | rev) > "$tgt_wd"/"$filename"
done `

Comment: In PowerShell you should be able to cobble something together like `(... -split ',')[1,2,3,-2,-1]`, but fixing the input data is the recommended approach.

Comment: Very difficult in batch, I would use Powershell as Ansgar recommended.

Comment: I am trying something like this, but not working out. I am not a powershell expert. can anyone guide me.
`$path = "C:\IE3BW0047A_08112017133859.csv"
Get-Content $path -split(",")[1,2,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1] | set-content C:\IE3BW0047A_08112017133859_fixed.csv`

Comment: Got it working: 
`Get-Content  $path| Foreach {"$($_.split(',')[0,1,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1])"}` but how can i add a delimiter to the output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solution:

```
$path = "C:\IE3BW0047A_08112017133859.csv"
Get-Content  $path| Foreach {"$($_.split(',')[0,1,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1] -join '|')"} | set-content C:\IE3BW0047A_08112017133859_filter.csv
```